# Does the standard specify whether a lambda capturing by value captures the parent object, or just the member being accessed?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

First example:

```
struct State
{
    SomeLargeObjectThatTakesTimeToCopy obj;
    int x;
} myState;

auto f = [=]() { return myState.x * 2; };
```

Does the entire `myState` struct get copied, even though, technically, only the `x` member is used?

Second example:

```
struct State
{
    struct SubState
    {
        int x;
    };

    std::vector<SubState> subStates;
} myState;

auto f = [=]() { return myState.subStates[0].x * 2; };
```

Again, does the entire `myState` object get copied? If not, then does the entire `subStates` member get copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `myState` is a local variable (defined in the body of a function), `myState` would get captured; lambda can only capture whole variables, not bits and pieces.

If you take your examples as-is, nothing gets captured; lambdas can't capture global variables.

Comment: So there's no room for optimization by the compiler? I would expect it to be fairly easy to simplify the above examples.

Comment: It's not as easy as it looks at first glance;  the compiler isn't allowed to elide any of the side-effects of the copy constructors or destructors involved.

Comment: Hm. That's an interesting point. It's a little disappointing, but I suppose it was also wishful thinking. :) If you have the standard handy, I'd like to know which section it is that specifies that.

Comment: The section on lambdas says that the generated class for the lambda has to have essentially the same members with the same effects as how it's specified in the standard.